# `this` is undefined in Dev Tools when using arrow function

Tags: javascript, typescript, webpack, arrow-functions

I'm using arrow functions and I'm debugging with Chrome and Firefox Dev Tool. I am getting, `this` as undefined, even though the code still works.

For Example: When paused on the following breakpoint, I type `this` in the console, and it comes out `undefined`, even though the `console.log` shows the correct `this`:

```js
class A {
    f = () => {
        debugger;
        console.log(this);
    };
}
new A().f();
```

My assumption is, that it has something to do with source-maps.

Here are the tools I use in order to build the my code:

- webpack (devtool: eval)
- babel-loader (es5 preset)
- typescript-loader

Comment: Simple code example to reproduce this issue will be greatly appreciate.

Comment: I'm getting this same issue - I swear it _used_ to work. Did you ever get to the bottom of it? I have some code to reproduce the issue

Comment: Looks like the [TypeScript bug report](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/2617) from 2015 is still open.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

The problem is that the chrome debugger believes that the `this` in the source code refers to the run-time `this`, but `this` inside a arrow function in typescript source code is actually transformed to `_this`, so it's showing you the wrong object.

This is why it's only a problem in the debugger and the code still works fine. When I need to debug something where this is a problem, I just copy it to the console and prepend it with an underscore.

Comment: Wow, where is this documented, I had no idea

Comment: I guess not only in typescritp : same problem and same solution with babel

Answer (score 1):

This might be an issue because JS arrow functions don't have `this`, the value of `this` might be referencing the object containing your arrow function, per [Arrow functions revisited](https://javascript.info/arrow-functions#arrow-functions-have-no-this) and [MDN's article on Arrow function expressions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)